# How many users see Google search results just for their own country?

Tags: geotargeting, country-specific, search-results

Are there any stats about how many Google/Bing users may be selecting country (as in the pic) in the SERP?[image]

As Susan says in [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/62399?hl=en) that geotargeting in GWT only works when users select a country as in the pic above. If it's small percentage then there won't be much use geotargeting wesite/pages by Webmasters.

Comment: Geotargeting doesn't only work when a user selects the country drop down, it also works on higher level. For example if you are using google.co.in you will get more results from India than doing the same search from google.com.

Comment: No, if I go to google.com it automatically redirects me to google.co.in, there is no choice.

Comment: Try clicking 'Google.com' in the very bottom right of the screen.

Comment: Local users automatically get redirected to their local Google versions, where they are served localized results automatically. The country-setting is an additional restrict (past normal geotargeting) to limit to country-specific sites.

Comment: @AgA You can turn off that redirect by visiting http://www.google.com/ncr

Answer (score 1):

You can use Adwords to get this numbers. On creating campaign start typing your location and you will get a list of locations and reach you can get.
[https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1722045?hl=en](http://wordpressgeekhelp.blogspot.com/2015/09/understanding-ad-reach.html)

[image]